# When setting up the config file for Nginx, what does $host and $http_upgrade mean?

Tags: nginx

When setting up a config file for nginx that should run a website that uses WebSockets, all the tutorials say to use this:

```
location /wsapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://websiteName;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

What exactly are $host and $http_upgrade?  Are they pseudovariables that need to be replaced?

Answer (score 7):

`$http_upgrade` is replaced by HTTP header with name `Upgrade`.

`$host` is either:

- Host name from the request line
- Host name from the Host request header field
- Server name matching the request

nginx replaces these variables with actual contents. The full list of nginx variables are listed in http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html